# Wait block doesn't test if storage has space

Tags: anylogic

My wait block should test if my pallet rack has enough space to store my pallets. So when I have 20 pallets and my store has space for 15, 15 should be stored and the other 5 pallets should wait in my wait block until the pallet rack has space again.
The problem is that I get an error that there are no empty cells which means that the pallets which don't have space not wait in my block but go trough the wait block and that causes an error.
Where is the problem? Wait block and rack pick are attached.

[waitblock_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQZxD.png)

[rackpick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYKVi.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFxPw.png)

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused by what you are showing? Where exactly is it triggered? (click on the first blue link in the error msg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to using `RestrictedAreaStart` and `RestrictedAreaEnd` blocks: Simply queue agents before and set the capacity of the restricted area to your pallet capacity.

Much easier (and less error-prone) than your manual approach.

Comment: Hi @User1900, Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)